# relation model between two models: null value

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I would like to make a relation between two models `User` and `Task` using [backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/).
I would like for each `Task` to get the `User` model.
The relation between the two model is the following:

```
taskModel.creator_id = userModel.id
```

Here is my code (1) (2)

The issue is the following (3):
When I try to fetch the models of task I get for the `attributes.user` the null value.

---

(1)

```
// TaskModel
var Task = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

    relations: [
        {
            type: 'HasOne',
            key: 'user',
            relatedModel: User
        }
    ],

    urlRoot: 'url_get_tasks'
});
```

---

(2)

```
// UserModel
var User = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({

    urlRoot: "url_get_users"

});
```

---

(3)

```
user = new User();
user.fetch();
console.log(user.attributes); // {id: 1, .....}

task = new Task();
task.fetch();
console.log(task.attributes); // {id: 12, creator_id: 1, user: null} ???
```

---

Why the `task.attributes.user` have the `null` value?

Answer (score 0):

Your relation on Task should be something like:

```
   {
       type: 'HasOne',
       key: 'user',
       keySource: 'creator_id',
       relatedModel: User
   }
```

(You're expecting it to use `creator_id` for the association but never told it that.)